# redirect specific ip range in IIS

Tags: iis, web.config

I want to **redirect** [not blocking them] all the ip's in between 83.116.119.0 to 255.255.255.0 Please help me to write a pattern in my code(IPTOBEBLOCKED).
Am a newbie in web.config , Here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <clear />
        <rule name="Redirect Japan Users" enabled="true" stopProcessing="false">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="IPTOBEBLOCKED"/>
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.net/jp/" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not meaning netmask?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen thanks for the comment. I want to redirect users from these ip range, not blocking them.

Comment: @Lenniey hi, i dont want block that ips...

Comment: I mean, do you really mean the range is odd like you described, or does the latter part mean netmask?

Comment: @bibinjohn yes, my linked answer achieves the blocking part via the **IIS Rewrite** module, you can alter the action as you like.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen it was just an example. My aim is to redirect all the users from japan to http://example.net/jp/

Comment: @Lenniey  Ok. But am a newbie in IIS, so its seems like too difficult to me